# Redmine query is very slow after upgrading from MySql 5.7 to 8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, redmine, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Recently we upgraded the MySql version for Redmine from 5.7 to 8.0.32. After the upgrade the MyPage query is taking a very long time to execute (Around 1 minute). Previously in version 5.7 it used to execute within a few seconds.

On initial research looks like MySql 8 uses derived query optimization concept due to which the logic that the query is interpreted in 5.7 and 8 is different.

Redmine Version: 4.1.1.stable (Tried this on latest redmine version 5.0.5 but faced the same issue. Also all the appropriate index have been done as well)

MyPage Query:

```
SELECT
  issues.id AS t0_r0,
  issues.tracker_id AS t0_r1,
  issues.project_id AS t0_r2,
  issues.subject AS t0_r3,
  issues.description AS t0_r4,
  issues.due_date AS t0_r5,
  issues.category_id AS t0_r6,
  issues.status_id AS t0_r7,
  issues.assigned_to_id AS t0_r8,
  issues.priority_id AS t0_r9,
  issues.fixed_version_id AS t0_r10,
  issues.author_id AS t0_r11,
  issues.lock_version AS t0_r12,
  issues.created_on AS t0_r13,
  issues.updated_on AS t0_r14,
  issues.start_date AS t0_r15,
  issues.done_ratio AS t0_r16,
  issues.estimated_hours AS t0_r17,
  issues.parent_id AS t0_r18,
  issues.root_id AS t0_r19,
  issues.lft AS t0_r20,
  issues.rgt AS t0_r21,
  issues.is_private AS t0_r22,
  issues.position AS t0_r23,
  issues.remaining_hours AS t0_r24,
  issues.story_points AS t0_r25,
  issues.closed_on AS t0_r26,
  issue_statuses.id AS t1_r0,
  issue_statuses.name AS t1_r1,
  issue_statuses.is_closed AS t1_r2,
  issue_statuses.position AS t1_r3,
  issue_statuses.default_done_ratio AS t1_r4,
  projects.id AS t2_r0,
  projects.name AS t2_r1,
  projects.description AS t2_r2,
  projects.homepage AS t2_r3,
  projects.is_public AS t2_r4,
  projects.parent_id AS t2_r5,
  projects.created_on AS t2_r6,
  projects.updated_on AS t2_r7,
  projects.identifier AS t2_r8,
  projects.status AS t2_r9,
  projects.lft AS t2_r10,
  projects.rgt AS t2_r11,
  projects.inherit_members AS t2_r12,
  projects.default_version_id AS t2_r13,
  projects.default_assigned_to_id AS t2_r14
FROM
  issues
  INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = issues.project_id
  INNER JOIN issue_statuses ON issue_statuses.id = issues.status_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN enumerations ON enumerations.id = issues.priority_id
WHERE
  (projects.status <> 9
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM enabled_modules em
    WHERE em.project_id = projects.id AND em.name='issue_tracking'
  ))
  AND (
    issues.status_id IN (SELECT id FROM issue_statuses WHERE is_closed=FALSE)
    AND issues.assigned_to_id IN ('1051', '2643')
    AND projects.status IN ('1')
  )
ORDER BY
  enumerations.position DESC,
  issues.updated_on DESC,
  issues.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Explain for MySQL 8.0.32

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | issue_statuses |  | ALL | PRIMARY |  |  |  | 19 | 100 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | issue_statuses |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_issue_statuses_on_is_closed | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issue_statuses.id | 1 | 89.47 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE |  |  | ALL |  |  |  |  |  | 100 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | projects |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | .project_id | 1 | 9 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | issues |  | ref | issues_project_id,index_issues_on_status_id,index_issues_on_assigned_to_id | issues_project_id | 4 | .project_id | 1917 | 0.03 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | enumerations |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_enumerations_on_id_and_type | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issues.priority_id | 1 | 100 |  |
| 2 | MATERIALIZED | em |  | ALL | enabled_modules_project_id |  |  |  | 3545 | 10 | Using where |

Explain for MySQL 5.7

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | issues |  | range | issues_project_id,index_issues_on_status_id,index_issues_on_assigned_to_id | index_issues_on_assigned_to_id | 5 |  | 2560 | 100 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | issue_statuses |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_issue_statuses_on_is_closed | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issues.status_id | 1 | 89.47 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | issue_statuses |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issues.status_id | 1 | 100 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY | enumerations |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,index_enumerations_on_id_and_type | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issues.priority_id | 1 | 100 |  |
| 1 | PRIMARY | projects |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | deermine.issues.project_id | 1 | 9 | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | em |  | ref | enabled_modules_project_id | enabled_modules_project_id | 5 | deermine.projects.id | 5 | 10 | Using where |

As you can see, in 5.7 all the rows are being pulled in single query where as for 8.0.32 it is being pulled in multiple query.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you include `EXPLAIN {query}` output in your question. I found the [issue structure here](https://github.com/redmine/redmine/blob/937124443caff1675f5719a6bb6b77ec6941648a/app/models/issue_query.rb#L380)

Comment: Check some other posts related to mysql performance in general, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469293/database-performance-drop-after-upgrade-to-mysql-8-0-20?noredirect=1#comment111610311_62469293

Comment: check these points 
Analyze query execution plans.
Ensure proper indexing.
Review MySQL configuration.
Use the latest Redmine version.
Optimize the database.

Comment: @danblack, the explain query has been added in the description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this issue by turning of the 'materialization' switch off in the optimizer_switch in MySQL 8. After turning off the materialization switch, SQL is not creating temp tables for where exists conditions which is leading to faster execution of the queries.

The execution time drop from 1+ minutes to less than a millisecond.

Comment: this solve our cpu reaching 100% all the time, but we are still seeing a lot of slow queries, we noticed in the explain command that instead of using PRIMARY/SUBQUERY it use SIMPLE in select type column, did you do any other change to the mysql optimizer ?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and we changed `materialization=off` in the optimizer_switch but it solved only partially the issue.

After that, we set `materialization=on,semijoin=off` and we got EXACTLY the same execution plan in MySQL 8 as we had in MySQL 5.7.